# Restricting AWS S3 Bucket access to a single role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to restrict access to an S3 bucket to a single EC2 role. I've attached the following bucket policy to the bucket, and the bucket has public access turned off. However when the policy is applied, I can still get to the bucket using curl from an instance without the role attached. Can anyone let me know what I'm missing?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": [
                        "AROQQQCCCZZDDVVQQHHCC:*",
                        "123456789012"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": [
                        "AROQQQCCCZZDDVVQQHHCC:*",
                        "123456789012"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userid": [
                        "AROQQQCCCZZDDVVQQHHCC:*",
                        "123456789012"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've already found [How to Restrict Amazon S3 Bucket Access to a Specific IAM Role](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/). But, you're using what looks like the policy for cross-account access. If your EC2 role and S3 bucket are in the same account, just use the final DENY policy statement.

Comment: @craigcaulfield I've removed the two allow statements, and still get the same result. I must be missing something obvious, as it seems that whatever I do the bucket is accessible to everything within my account (but not outside it).

Comment: If you _REMOVE_ your bucket policy, can "an instance without the role attached still download the file"? Please test it, since such access is probably _not_ coming from the bucket policy.

Comment: Hi, I've tried removing the policy, and in that case, I can access the bucket both from instances with the role, and without.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following S3 policy should do the job. Remember to replace role arn with the correct one which I assume it attached to your EC2 instance. Also, make sure your ec2 role has correct policy to perform list,get,put,delete actions.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ExplicitDenyAllActions",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowListForIAMRole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/ROLENAME"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowDeleteGetPutForIAMRole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/ROLENAME"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:Delete*",
            "s3:Get*",
            "s3:Put*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAllActionForUser",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/USERNAME"
          ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Useful docs where you can find more info -> [AWS docs on s3 policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/)

Comment: Thanks @MC_, however I've tried this and have the same result: an instance without the role attached can still download the file.

Comment: I am not too sure how thats possible. However I updated my answer so that there is no condition on deny action. Please make sure that you add your IAM user arn to the last allow block just in case. Try that and let me know.

Comment: Hi, I've tried removing the condition on the deny action, and with that applied no-one can access the bucket, whether they have the role or not, so it seems it is at least evaluating the condition.